# installing dkms fails to work

Tags: centos, virtual-machines, virtualbox, yum, centos6

I would like to install dkms to install the VBGuessAdditions but

```
yum install dkms
```

always results in an error

> loaded pluggins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security Loading
>   mirror speeds from cached hostfile Could not retrieve mirrorlist
>   http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=6&arch=x86_64&repo=os error was
>   14: PYCURL ERROR 6 - "Could not resoltve host 'mirrorlist.centos.org'"
>   Error: Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo:base

Answer (score 1):

Your DNS servers are broken.  What do you have in /etc/resolv.conf?  Replace it with something like this:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

If that doesn't fix it, make sure you have outbound connectivity, and there's no iptables rules blocking things.

Comment: Thank you I have got an error stating that **No package dkms is available**

Comment: DKMS appears to be in RPMForge.  Do you have that repository enabled?